# php sort values of a array

Tags: php, sorting

id love a little help with the sort function here, im trying to figure it out but cant.

```
<?php
  if ($handle = opendir('uploads')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != ".."){ 
      sort ($file);
        $thelist .= '<li><a href="uploads/'.$file.'" target="_top">'.$file.'</a><img src="uploads/'.$file.$media.'" width="25" height="25"</li>';
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }

?>

<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

so this doesnt sort...

and the following will, but wont display some files.

im only interested in the sort function for the top code, i paid a guy to write the following half to try to understand the function sort

from what i can figure were suggesting the $file displays for a list then for a photo using the various $.. im stuck with whats stopping the $file from getting alphabeticaly arranged before being told what to display, (the best i got to was a list of the number ones displaying alphabetical (numerical yes) but its not sorting)

```
function showDir($dir, $i, $lar, $lon, $lin)
    {

        print("<style>.box { border-style: outset ; border-width: 1px ; border-color: #A3C5CC ; border-radius: 8px ; -moz-border-radius: 8px }</style>") ;

        print("<script language='JavaScript'>
        <!--
        function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
          window.open(theURL,winName,features);
        }
        //-->
        </script>") ;


        $i++;
        if($checkDir = opendir($dir))
        {
            $cFile = 0;
            while($file = readdir($checkDir))
            {
                if($file != "." && $file != "..")
                {
                    if(!is_dir($dir . "/" . $file))
                    {
                        $listFile[$cFile] = $file;
                        $cFile++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(count(@$listFile) > 0)
            {
                print("<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0' border='0'><tr>") ;

                sort($listFile);

                $x = 0 ;

                for($k = 0; $k < count($listFile); $k++)
                {
                    $spacer = "";

                    for($l = 0; $l < $i; $l++)
                        $spacer .= "&emsp;";

                    if($x % $lin == 0)
                        print("</tr><tr>") ;

                    $img = $listFile[$k] ;

                    $tmp = explode(".", $img) ;

                    $x++ ;

                    if($tmp[1] == 'jpg' OR $tmp[1] == 'bmp' OR $tmp[1] == 'gif' OR $tmp[1] == 'png' 
                    OR $tmp[1] == 'tga' OR $tmp[1] == 'tif' OR $tmp[1] == 'eps')
                    {

                        print("<td>") ;
                        print("<table class='box' bgcolor='#9ABBC1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='" . ($lon+10) . "' height='" . ($lar+27) . "'><tr>") ;

                        print("<td align='center'><small><b>" . ($k+1) . "</b></small></td></tr><tr>") ;

                        print("<td align='center'>") ;

                        $srcimg = $dir . "/" . $spacer . $img ;

                        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($srcimg);

                        print("<a href='#' onClick=\"MM_openBrWindow('display.php?img=$srcimg&lon=$width&lar=$height','','width=" . $width . ",height=" . $height . ",left=100,top=100,scrollbars=no,toolbars=no')\">") ;
                        print("<img src='" . $srcimg . "' width='" . $lar . "' height='" . $lon . "' alt='" . $img . "' title='" . $img . "' border='0'></a></td>");
                        print("</tr></table>\n") ;
                        print("</td>") ;
                    }
                    else 
                        $x-- ;
                }
                print("</tr></table>\n") ;

                print("<br><small>" . $k . " Images displayed<b></b></small>") ;
            }
            closedir($checkDir);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function instead of `readdir`.

> sorting_order By default, the sorted order is alphabetical in
> ascending order. If the optional sorting_order is set to
> SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING, then the sort order is alphabetical in
> descending order. If it is set to SCANDIR_SORT_NONE then the result is
> unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
if ($handle = opendir('uploads')) {


    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($file != "." && $file != ".."){


            $files[] = $file;


        }

    }
    sort ($files);
    $thelist = '';
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $thelist .= '<li><a href="uploads/'.$file.'" target="_top">'.$file.'</a><img src="uploads/'.$file.'" width="25" height="25"</li>';
    }
    closedir($handle);

}
?>
    <ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

Comment: well it needed a file = file of some description

Comment: i dont get the $the list - ' '   its meaning just "something"

Comment: and the foreach would have been news to me